# How to avoid duplicate keys with MySQL and JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I'm working with a Java application using JPA/Hibernate and MySQL and trying to understand the correct way to do something that seems like it should be straightforward.

**The Goal**

The goal is: to allow two threads running in parallel (each with their own transaction, of course) to query for, and then insert if not found, a unique value into the database, and do so without the possibility of any exceptions being thrown by MySQL.

So each thread first does a query to see if the record exists, and then if not, inserts that record, and then is done. Sounds simple.

**The Theory**

I thought the possibility of exceptions could be eliminated by setting `LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` on the query, because this would translate to `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE`, which means the first thread's query would set an exclusive write lock on the record, and so the second thread's query would block until the first thread committed, whereby the second thread would then wake up and be able to see the new record.

After playing with MySQL directly I realize there's something basic that I'm missing because the second thread is in fact not blocking during its query.

**The Practice**

I created a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`A` (
  `id` BIGINT( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
  `name` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ) ,
  UNIQUE (`name`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Then performed the following commands in two separate windows **X** and **Y**, doing each command one at a time, first in **X** then in **Y**:

```
1  SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
2  BEGIN;
3  SELECT * FROM A WHERE `name`='Jones' FOR UPDATE;
4  INSERT INTO A (`name`) VALUES ('Jones');
5  COMMIT;
```

When performing this test, each statement is accepted immediately and error-free in both **X** and **Y**, with zero rows returned by statement #3 in both, until an error occurs after command #4 in **Y**:

```
ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

Actually this is not unexpected... what is unexpected (to me) is that **Y** doesn't block when I execute *command #3*. Once both threads have queried for `'Jones'` and seen nothing, my idea is obviously doomed because they can't both be right.

I thought the whole point of `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` was that it set an exclusive lock on the record, which should cause **Y** to block on statement #3.

**The Question**

What am I missing? Is it even possible to do what I want, either in JPA or even MySQL?

Notes:

- MySQL version is `5.5.23-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)`
- Changing to `SERIALIZABLE` doesn't help anything.

Comment: What you're missing, AFAIK, is that the 3rd statement locks the rows where name = 'Jones', and not the whole table. Since there is none of such rows, nothing is locked.

Comment: InnoDB supports [gap and next-key locks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-record-level-locks.html), but apparently it doesn't use them in this case.